# J2ME avoid compatibility mode on Nokia 5800

Tags: java-me, nokia

My MIDlet uses Forms as well as Canvas. When I navigate into a canvas, my Nokia 5800 goes into backward compatibility mode and starts showing all those buttons. How do I avoid it.

P.S. I am not making use of any button inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your jad file

There are various options, the most likely one you require is

Nokia-MIDlet-On-Screen-Keypad: no

The other options are 
Nokia-MIDlet-On-Screen-Keypad: gameactions
Nokia-MIDlet-On-Screen-Keypad: navigationkeys

Nokia have a full explanation on how this affects your application here
http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Using_on-screen_keypad_in_MIDlets_in_S60_5th_Edition_devices

Answer (score 1):

put the following line into our JAD:

```
Nokia-MIDlet-On-Screen-Keypad: no
```